# Entity Framework OrderBy On Joined Collection

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using PredicateBuilder and LINQKit to build a fairly complex dynamic query. The model structure looks a bit like

```
MediaGallery (one-to-many) MediaGalleryItems (one-one) MediaItems
```

I'm eager loading this whole relationship and that part is working fine.

Each MediaGalleryItem has an 'Order' property which allows items in the gallery to have a specific order. I need to OrderBy this, so I kind of want to do:

```
IQueryable<MediaGallery> query = ...
... lots of stuff ...
query = query.OrderBy(m => m.MediaGalleryItems.Order)
```

But obviously that wont work as MediaGalleryItems is a collection of MediaGalleryItem objects. I also tried

```
query = query.OrderBy(m => m.MediaGalleryItems.OrderBy(mgi => mgi.SortOrder));
```

which compiles but doesn't work. It seems like it should be easy, am I missing something obvious?

**Edit**: I should have said that I'm restricting to a single MediaGallery, so if I was hand writing SQL it might make sense to do something like this to reduce DB trips. Joachim Isaksson's comment rightly pointed out this could result in a mess for more than one MediaGallery, if you weren't ordering by the MediaGallery.Id first.

I suppose my question is therefore; is there any way of forcing Linq to output the SQL I need here, or should I make it easy on myself and do a second trip to the DB?

Comment: You can't really order by a collection, what would be the expected order of MediaGalleries if MediaGallery1 has 2 Items with order 1 and 4 while MediaGalley2 has 2 items with order 2 and 3?

Comment: Good point, thanks. However I should have said that I'm selecting out a single MediaGallery so it seems logical in order to reduce DB trips in this case. If it's not possible I can understand why thinking about the wider picture.

Comment: what `query` is? It is a `MediaGallery` collection? Please, post sample data and expected results. Perhaps you are looking for `firstordefault`?

Comment: If you're trying to order a sub-collection in a query, I can't think of any way of doing it, in fact they're afaik usually (default?) mapped to a Set<> so even in the case of the database sorting it, it'd be stored unordered in memory. I'd fetch the result and order the sub-collection using Linq2Objects in memory when I need it to be sorted instead.

Comment: Thanks. Ordering in memory after the query has returned seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You must order your items in your application before you show them to the user. Eager loading don't offer ordering navigation properties (relations) and even if it does EF will probably not ensure that this order is maintained after materialization because it doesn't use any ordered collections (if you allow lazy loading it uses hash set based collections).

If you want ordered relations you must use projection:

```
var query = from x in context.MediaGallery
            where x ...
            select new 
                {
                    MediaGellery = x,
                    MediaGalleryItems = x.MediaGalleryItems.OrderBy(i => i.Order)
                };
```